# jQuery Clone Table Row After First Clone

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a `dynamic form` with huge `select lists` instead of querying my database for each `select option`. I want to just `clone` one row outside my `PHP` foreach loop that has the full set of options.

Right now I am doing something like this:

```
<table id="test" class="table">
<tr>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="type[]">
            <option value="20">Auto Rental</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="distance_type[]">
            <option value="1">Nearby</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr class="clone">
    <td>
        <select class="readonly form-control" name="type[]" disabled>
            <option value="20">Boat Rental 1</option>
            <option value="20">Boat Rental 2</option>
            <option value="20">Boat Rental3</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select class="readonly form-control" name="distance_type[]" disabled>
            <option value="1">Nearby</option>
            <option value="1">Far</option>
            <option value="1">10 miles</option>
        </select>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<a class="add" href="#">Add New Row</a>
```

Javascript

```
         $(".add ").on('click', function () {
         var clone = $('.clone').closest('tr')[0];
         $(clone).clone().insertAfter(clone);
         $('.readonly').attr("disabled", false)
         });
```

I disable the select input so it doesn't get submitted unless the "add" button is clicked. The problem is when I click the add button, it ends up enabling it and also adding another field. I pretty much just want to hide the first instance and when clicked it enables it and then when I click add again it adds the new fields, etc.

Here is live version https://jsfiddle.net/f4gp9uky/

Tried some stuff like `$('#el'):nth-child(n+3).hide();` But that doesn't work.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like

```js
var $clone = $('.clone');
$(".add ").on('click', function() {
  if ($clone.hasClass('hidden')) {
    $clone.removeClass('hidden').find('.readonly').prop("disabled", false)
  } else {
    $clone.clone().appendTo($clone.parent());
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="test" class="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control" name="type[]">
        <option value="20">Auto Rental</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control" name="distance_type[]">
        <option value="1">Nearby</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="clone hidden">
    <td>
      <select class="readonly form-control" name="type[]" disabled>
        <option value="20">Boat Rental 1</option>
        <option value="20">Boat Rental 2</option>
        <option value="20">Boat Rental3</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <select class="readonly form-control" name="distance_type[]" disabled>
        <option value="1">Nearby</option>
        <option value="1">Far</option>
        <option value="1">10 miles</option>
      </select>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<a class="add" href="#">Add New Row</a>
```

Comment: ^ This is good, but seems to start duplicating the clones in sets after 4 clicks.  The first two click seem fine though.